# Subdivision Surface on curved mesh

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to delete those ugly lines visible in the cylindrical shape of the lens. What is causing them is the added edge loops I made for the protruding detail with the switch. The problem is that if I delete those edges, it'll look even worse because of the n-gons. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is how you place edge loops in your mesh over the curved surface.

Since it is a cylindrical surface edge loops cant be placed by simple subdivision, because that will yield a flat planar surface breaking the curvature of your otherwise cylindrical body.

When placing edge loops you need to make sure they are equidistant from the mesh center or use *Subdivide Smooth* for a curvature approximation.

[image: Curved Loops]

Comment: Excellent. I'll make sure to do that next time. Although I just tested Subdivide Smooth on a cylinder and those lines appear if you make enough cuts. The lines are noticeable even when doing 2 cuts: [Picture](http://puu.sh/qbJrK/6305866615.jpg) The thing is that I can't do it that way on my model without deleting the protruding detail. What would be perfect is an add-on that lets you line up the vertices with a desired radius from the origin of the cylinder. That would solve everything, if what you say is right. BTW, how did you slide the 2 edge cuts you made at the same time, at opposite dir?

Comment: Well I'll be frank, fixing your model probably won't be easy without remaking at least part of it. Unfortunately this kind of work is more suited for CAD like NURBS or Solid Modelling applications; Blender is particularly unsuited for this type of workflow unfortunately. For this I would suggest the spin tool `Alt`+`R`that uses the 3D Cursor and the point of view as center for generating flawless revolution geometry.

Comment: The two edge loops sliding were actually created using the *bevel* operator. Select one single edge loop and press `Ctrl`+`B` and it will create two parallel loops using absolute distances.

Comment: Alright, I'll remake the detail. Thanks for the bevel tip! That'll be useful. What do you mean by "this kind of work", exactly? What "type of workflow" are you referring to?

Comment: I'm talking about solid modeling of geometric shapes or "hard-edge" type of objects like mechanical parts, non deforming or non organic shapes, based on precise measurements and intersections of basic shapes. This thing is usually done in CAD applications like AutoCAD, Rhino, MoI 3D etc, where you can easily use Boolean operations, extrusions, revolutions, intersections, trimming and extending, and beveling for perfect geometry and smooth curves

Comment: I'm confused. I thought Blender was more suited for hard surface objects rather than organics.

Comment: It's quite the other way around, Blender is primarily aimed at animators and character creation and subdivision based modeling for animation and feature film production. That is not to say that it can't be used for hard-edge modeling. It's tools are actually quite flexible and versatile, but generally speaking mesh based geometry and subdivision modeling in general are largely regarded as less suited for CAD work. Hell I work primarily in architecture and mostly do CAD based work in Blender, but I have to admit that there always a certain resistance, and I often have to fight the technology

Comment: Well, every hard surface 3D artist that I know and that I've seen on the web use either Blender, 3Ds Max or Maya, so you're really confusing me here :P. Going back to the main topic. Even if you use Smooth Subdivide every time you need a loop cut (which would be a pain), it still doesn't solve the problem when you have to put the loop closer to another. The same line appears. This question is not yet answered. The only thing that occurs to me that would make the lines disappear is to subdivide the whole cylinder equally whenever you need a loop cut, but I refuse to believe that is the best opt

Comment: Well this very same problem that we are discussing is exactly why mesh modeling tools are not the most adequate for this kind of work, you should never have to deal with these problems in the first place. Anyway as I said no easy way around this, rotate your loopcuts instead of moving them. Place the 3D cursor at the center of the cylinder curvature and preform rotation with the center on the 3D cursor position.

Answer (score 0):

Cylinders and spheres are prone to render errors when they contain faces of different sizes. In your case the switch also produces irregularities not only in the horizontal but also in the vertical direction (both top and bottom of the switch)

As far as I can tell your model is already made out of several objects/meshes. If it's not absolutely necessary to have the switch and the tube as one single object I would separate them and collapse the unnecessary edge loops.

Comment: I didn't bother about joining all the parts because this is just a high poly model to bake a normal map to a lower poly model, but I want to avoid dividing the mesh further because it may become cumbersome. I'll do it if it's the best choice, of course, but is there an easy way to even out the size of the faces of the cylinder without deleting any edges?